# customized template for angular2-notifications

Tags: html, angular

[angular2-notifications](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-notifications#example) library has default view of notification.[check this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular2-notifications-example?file=app%2Fexample.component.ts)

but i am looking to customize HTML of notification look.
ex
[image]

its code for HTML is

```
<div class="alert alert-custom alert-primary" role="alert">
    <div class="alert-icon"><i class="flaticon-warning"></i></div>
    <div class="alert-text">A simple primary alert—check it out!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks they support it with template ref and viewchild , not sure the best option but you can try something like the following in your component:-

```
<ng-template #customHtml let-text="text">
<div class="alert alert-custom alert-primary" role="alert">
    <div class="alert-icon"><i class="flaticon-warning"></i></div>
    <div class="alert-text">{{text}}</div>
</div>
</ng-template>
```

and in your component ts :-

```
  //set viewchild
  @ViewChild('customHtml') customHtml: TemplateRef<any>;
```

and pass in the context in the notification service with templateRef before creation of notifcation:-

```
let context: any = {text: 'A simple primary alert—check it out!'};
this._service.html(this.customHtml, null, null, null, context);
```

[StackBlitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-f4uezn)

Comment: thank you for reply, I read this in library and tried but not working, but can you edit that stackblitz example to make it work.

Comment: I think the stackblitz you shared uses an older version of angular notification which don't support it. I have added a sample with new version